# Length of a tensor product with an extension of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be an arbitrary extension of a field $k$, and let $M$ be a $k$-algebra with finite length, i.e. whose maximal chain of submodules are finite. Is it true that length of $M$ is equal to length of $M \otimes_{k}K$? Definitely length of $M \otimes_{k}K \geq$ that of $M$ since all chain of submodules can be also extended to modules over $K$, however I don't know how to show the other inverse. Or maybe they are not equal, but I don't know any concrete examples that they are not equal. Could you give me some hint or reference for this question?

P.S. Here, the length of $M\otimes_{k}K$ is the length of it as $M\otimes_{k}K$-modules; the length of maximal chain of submodules of $M \otimes_{k}K$.

Comment: Presumably you meant "let $M$ be a $k$-module with finite length," and you meant length as a $k$-module, aka, dimension of $M$ as a vector space over $k$. Correct?

Comment: @peterag No, I mean them as a $k$-algebra. For example, if $K$ is transcendental extension of $k$, then definitely this does not hold if we think length of $M \otimes_{k}K$ as a $k$-vector space.

Comment: So you don't mean the length of $M\otimes_k K$ as a $K$-module? (Sorry if I am being stubborn and stupid.)

Comment: @peterag Yes, I mean the length as a maximal length of chain of submodules of $M \otimes_{k}K$. (And you are totally fine! Thank you for concerning my question!)

Comment: So... if $K$ is a field, then $M\otimes_k K$ is a vector space over $K$, and its length (as a $K$-module) is its $K$-dimension. Agree?

Comment: @peterag Yes, I agree.

Comment: Then - since $M$ is a $k$-module, its length as a $k$-module is its dimension as a $k$-vector space. i.e., $M \simeq k^d$ as $k$-modules, some $d$, (all $k$-modules are free) and $M\otimes_kK \simeq K^d$ as $K$-modules, same $d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: let $K/k$ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$ and set $M := K$; then $M$ has length 1 whereas $M \otimes_{k} K \simeq \prod_{g \in G} K$ has length $|G|$.

Note also that $M \otimes_{k} K$ need not be Artinian, because the tensor product of (non-algebraic) field extensions may have positive Krull dimension, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979476/prove-that-the-tensor-product-of-non-algebraic-extensions-is-not-a-field) for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the concrete example and the link!

Comment: @user124697 I see I was indeed being 'stubborn and stupid' in the comments: you were NOT considering the length of $M$ as a $k$-module, but as an $M$-module.

Comment: @peterag Yes I considering it as an M-module. Thank you for consideration!